# vertically align two fontawesome icons

Tags: html

I want to display two font-awesome icons vertically aligned with each other. Currently, the output is like this:

[image]

my current code is:

```
        <div class="row text-center">

            <b> Value </b>

            <i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>

        </div>
```

What I want to end up with is below. It is the "sort" icon of font-awesome but I don't want to use a third icon due to functionality requirements.

[image]

Comment: hello, check my link in EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use flexbox for this as below

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.icons-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.icons-wrapper i.fa{
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row text-center container">

   <b> Value </b>

   <div class="icons-wrapper">
     <i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
   </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
CHECK this:  https://jsfiddle.net/w7utx236/3/

You can use `display: grid` to the wrapper of your icons

and then use for the wrapper of your icons

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 6px;(here setting px for your solution to look good)
```

Comment: this is final solution to your case https://jsfiddle.net/w7utx236/3/

Comment: This is honestly a bit weird, because you create a grid with only one row. Then, what happens is that both elements are put in the first place in that grid. They're just on top of each other in the Z-axis, they're not differently placed on the Y-axis

Answer (score 0):

With these icons, you don't need to align them vertically. You can just put them on top of each other, because the `fa-sort-up` icon is transparent in the bottom half and the `fa-sort-down` is transparent in the top half. To put them on top of each others, you can put them in a div container and put their css `display` property to `absolute`, like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-sort-up, .fa-sort-down {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Clicking won't work as expected though, and I'm not sure it can be fixed with this technique.

https://jsfiddle.net/jk5nd2wh/8/

Answer (score -2):

You could use a `table`:

```html
<div class="row text-center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan=2><b> Value </b></dt>

            <td><i class="fa fa-sort-up"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you could. but semantically this is one of the worst options. only use tables for tabular data...